# Trying to create a Withdraw Method with limit of 5 free transactions and any after will deduct a $1 fee. (// Begineer in Java)

Tags: java, account

I am working on an assignment where the user is allowed to withdraw and deposit money into their account. But it is my responsibility to have the code catch whenever the user goes over 5 transactions and then charge their account with $1. 
I so far created for the withdraw method this code :

```
public double withdraw(double amount) throws Exception {
    if( numtransactions <5){
    this.numtransactions++;
    return balance-amount; 
    // Stub
    }
    else {
        this.numtransactions++;
        this.balance-1;
        return balance-amount;
    }
    return balance - amount;
}
```

Eclipse gives me an error warning that at the line `this.balance-1;`
the "-" is considered a syntax error. 
How can I fix this issue and does this code make sense to do what it is intended to do?

My Deposits method is built similarly but with a few if and else statements to restrict other things and also have a few issues. But I am hoping to first cover this withdraw method and utilize what I learn from this method onto the deposits.

Thanks
Tom

Edit:

I have implemented the use of declaring this.balance with balance-=1 and both my withdraws method and deposit method are working correctly! 
Thank you for making my first experience on stackoverflow and amazing one!!

Comment: What is the datatype of balance?

Comment: the datatype of balance is a double, there is a lot more to the code. This is just a snippet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the line

```
this.balance - 1;
```

you are not assigning the result of that operation to any variable. If you want to reduce `balance`, you can use either of these (all are equivalent):

```
this.balance = this.balance - 1;
this.balance -= 1;
this.balance--;
```

Also, each with each withdraw, you would like to modify the `balance`:

```
this.balance -= amount;
```

**Why "-" is considered a syntax error?**

Java expects a variable in the left-hand part of an assignment and an expression in the right-hand part. When you do, for example:

```
2 - 1;
```

an assignment operator (`=`) is expected, because you cannot have an expression (in this case `2 - 1`) in the left-hand part.

Comment: @ShermanBachar Click in [edit] at the bottom of your question, then **add** (don't delete anything) the code you want, but you must specify that what you are adding is an edit.

Comment: I can show my correction on a specific code as a comment in return to you?

Comment: Not in a comment. Does your actual code compiles? Why you woult like to show your actual code? It throws an error?

Comment: no I just wanted to show you the snippet of code that I corrected with the suggestions you gave me :)

Comment: I don't think it's necessary. Feel free to accept this answer (or the one that helped you most) if it was useful and solved your problem: [How does accepting an answer work](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the right syntax. Try this:

```
public double withdraw(double amount) throws Exception {
    if( this.numtransactions <5){
       if(this.balance >= amount) {
          this.numtransactions++;
          this.balance -= amount;
          return this.balance; 
       }
    }
    else {
       if(this.balance >= (amount+1)) {  //anount + 1 to account for deduction fee
          this.numtransactions++;
          this.balance -= (amount + 1);
          return this.balance;
    }
    return this.balance;  //in case account does not have enough funds
}
```

Note: We only increment `numtransactions` if a withdrawal is successful. Hence, I have placed it inside the conditionals.

Comment: This makes the most sense.